# How should I transfer photo (jpeg) files from my ubuntu 14.04 PC and display them on my iPad, without using iTunes?

Tags: 14.04, photo-management, ios

I am very happy to manage my photo files centrally on my Ubuntu 14.04 PC. 
It is easy to mount an i-device onto the PC using a USB cable and opening Nautilus. (congrats for making that so seamless, developers!) Then I can copy jpegs FROM the directories of the i-devices TO my PC file system, using Nautilus file manager. 
But, I need to take photos FROM the PC, and copy them TO an i-app that can display them on an i-device. 
Does anybody have a practical way to do this without iTunes ? I have tried a number of apps which were recommended for Ubuntu 12, but nothing has worked.
I do not care what the i-device "thinks" about the pictures' dates, places, etc, I just need to carry the pictures and show them to people on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

A FTP client can transfer files both ways, you can download or upload files. So yeah, you can definitely move the photos TO the smartphone. Greetings.

Comment: TY, I have tried this. The JPEG file can be copied, but, the Photo app does not "know" that the photos are there. It just shows the same photos as before. My next try will be to put them in some sort of cloud service like flickr, but I'd really love to avoid that step.

Answer (score -1):

I use sftpd (ftp server) to transfer files from my smartphone (where I installed a ftp client, obviously) to my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04), anytime, anywhere, as long as both of them are running.

Comment: thanks, but that is not relevant to my question, which involves moving the photos TO the smartphone.